# Error "Cannot read property "matches" of undefined" when using "npm install"

Tags: npm, expo, npm-install

I'm trying to install [expo](https://docs.expo.io/) globally on my Windows 10 machine for a school assignement.

As the doc says, I've been trying the following command in my terminal :

```
$ npm install --global expo-cli
```

but it always gives me the same error :

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-07T13_43_16_562Z-debug.log
```

I've tried running `$ npm install -g expo-cli` instead but the same thing happens.

I haven't tried reinstalling node or anything yet because I need my pc up and running for this week and I'm not too accustomed to all that, I'd like to keep that a last resort if possible.

Has anyone ever encountered this error before ?

Comment: this appears to be a bug in npm. try `npm i -g npm@6` to get the latest patch version of npm 6

Comment: Switching from node 15 to node 12 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to those who replied but I "accidentally" fixed it myself.

Through my searching I ended up actually uninstalling node with `$ nvm uninstall v15.0.0` and I found myself obligated to download it again [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

Must've been a problem with the version I was using as suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and run command `npm install`.

Comment: I've seen multiple people say that online but since it's globally in my case and not a project, I don't know where I can find the exact folders I need to delete. 
I've found multiple `node_modules` folders in my files while looking though my installation to find the error, but I'm a complete novice so I don't really know which ones I should delete